Github action for memcheck on macos and windows using ctest?
To incorporate static code analysis into my github CI workflow, for completeness I would like to perform memory checking for both macos and windows. In principle, and I could very well be wrong, I would think it would be enough to perform memory checking using valgrind on ubuntu-latest, and if there are no memory leaks there, I would think the same would apply for windows and macos. Though suppose I did want to perform memory checking using
ctest -T memcheck -R <name of test> --output-on-failure

What tools can I install in the macos and windows build for this to work? For macos, I tried run: brew install valgrind in the workflow file, but I get this error:

Run brew install valgrind
valgrind: Linux is required for this software.
Error: valgrind: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

On the linux build, run: sudo apt-get -y install valgrind works without a problem of course.
